# SQL Server 2008 Row Insert and Update timestamps

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I need to add two columns to a database table in SQL Server 2008 R2:

- createTS - *date and time when row is inserted*
- updateTS - *date and time when row is updated*

I have a few questions:

1. What column data type should I employ for each of these?
2. `createTS` needs to be set only once, when the row is inserted. When I tried the `datetime` type for this column and added a *Default Value or Binding* of `getdate()`, the column value was appropriately set. Is this the best way to fulfill the purpose of this column? I considered [`timestamp` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms182776(v=sql.90)), but that is, in my opinion, nearly a misnomer!
3. `updateTS` needs to be set to the date and time of the moment when the row is updated. In SQL Server, there is no *ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP* (as in MySQL), so it looks like I have to resort to using a trigger. Is this right and how would I go about doing that?

So there is a starting point for anyone who would like to answer this question, here is the create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[names]
(
    [name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [createTS] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_names_createTS]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [updateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_names] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [name] ASC
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** make your clustered key (a) this wide (`nvarchar(64)` = 128 bytes!!) and it's also (b) not advisable to make it a variable length column (since those have additional overhead). A **good** clustering key would be narrow, unique, static (doesn't change), and ideally ever-increasing - an `INT IDENTITY` is almost perfect, anything more than 8-16 bytes is **horrendously** bad as a clustering key...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names]
(
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateTS] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CreateTS_DF DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    [UpdateTS] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL

)
```

PS
I think a smalldatetime is good enough.  You may decide differently.

Can you not do this at the "moment of impact" ?

In Sql Server, this is common:

```
Update dbo.MyTable 
Set 

ColA = @SomeValue , 
UpdateDS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Where...........
```

Sql Server has a "timestamp" datatype.

But it may not be what you think.

Here is a reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

Here is a little [RowVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ([synonym for timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177566%28v%3dsql.90%29)) example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names]
(
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    RowVers rowversion ,
    [CreateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CreateTS_DF DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    [UpdateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL

)


INSERT INTO dbo.Names (Name,UpdateTS)
select 'John' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Mary' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Paul' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]

Update dbo.Names Set Name = Name

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]
```

Maybe a complete working example:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Names]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names]
(
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    RowVers rowversion ,
    [CreateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CreateTS_DF DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    [UpdateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL

)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgKeepUpdateDateInSync_ByeByeBye ON dbo.Names
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

Update dbo.Names Set UpdateTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dbo.Names myAlias , inserted triggerInsertedTable where 
triggerInsertedTable.Name = myAlias.Name

END


GO






INSERT INTO dbo.Names (Name,UpdateTS)
select 'John' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Mary' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Paul' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]

Update dbo.Names Set Name = Name , UpdateTS = '03/03/2003' /* notice that even though I set it to 2003, the trigger takes over */

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]
```

Matching on the "Name" value is probably not wise.

Try this more mainstream example with a SurrogateKey

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Names]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names]
(
    SurrogateKey int not null Primary Key Identity (1001,1),
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    RowVers rowversion ,
    [CreateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CreateTS_DF DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    [UpdateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL

)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgKeepUpdateDateInSync_ByeByeBye ON dbo.Names
AFTER UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

   UPDATE dbo.Names
    SET UpdateTS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    From  dbo.Names myAlias
    WHERE exists ( select null from inserted triggerInsertedTable where myAlias.SurrogateKey = triggerInsertedTable.SurrogateKey)

END


GO






INSERT INTO dbo.Names (Name,UpdateTS)
select 'John' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Mary' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL select 'Paul' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]

Update dbo.Names Set Name = Name , UpdateTS = '03/03/2003' /* notice that even though I set it to 2003, the trigger takes over */

select *  ,  ConvertedRowVers = CONVERT(bigint,RowVers) from [dbo].[Names]
```

Comment: Doing this at the moment of impact is ideal, but from an application perspective, that warrants changes in many places. I would rather handle that at the database level... because it is perceived as a responsibility of the database to keep track of that information.

Comment: Then you're stuck with a trigger, as you suspect...as far as I know.  If you go that route, make sure you write "set based" trigger code, not "row by row" trigger code.

Comment: Okay... I don't know the distinction between set-based and row by row based trigger code.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662010/handling-multiple-records-in-a-ms-sql-trigger

Comment: In an nutshell, you see the INSERT I do above with John,Mary,Paul.  The trigger is going to run ONCE for that single INSERT (because I'm using 'union all', but all 3 rows will be available to you in the trigger code.   When I do the UPDATE "set name = name", the trigger is going to fire ONCE for that statement......as well.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using a trigger, you might like to consider creating a stored procedure to handle the `INSERT`s that takes most of the columns as arguments and gets the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which it includes in the final `INSERT` to the database. You could do the same for the `CREATE`. You may also be able to set things up so that users cannot execute `INSERT` and `CREATE` statements other than via the stored procedures.

I have to admit that I haven't actually done this myself so I'm not at all sure of the details.

Comment: The existing stored procedures are an extension to the application's business logic, so there are many of those that need to be updated. That is why triggers may be a preferable approach, as much as I dislike employing them for this very fundamental use case.