# How to generate timestamp value for binary(8) field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, timestamp

I need two timestamp fields in my table. One, of the timestamp type for update operation, and the one (binary(8)) for the insert one.

The timestamp type's value is auto generated by the sql server,
Where to get the value for that second column from?

Comment: But the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in SQL Server has absolutely **nothing** to do with a normal, human-readabel date & time.... it's just a binary "counter" of sorts.... if you need *timestamp* as in the date and time of an operation, you need to use `DATETIME2` in SQL Server 2008; for the `INSERT`, you can define a **default constraint** that will fill it automatically when a row is inserted; for the `UPDATE`, you'll need to add a trigger to that table

Comment: But why would you need to store a `timestamp` as `binary`? If you have a `binary` value representing a `timestamp` and you want to store this `timestamp`, wouldn't it be better to convert the `binary` into `timestamp` and then insert it into your database?

Comment: @marc_s Where did you get the information from that I think of that type as being datetime representative? ...

Comment: @drigoangelo I need to create a table with that values. Timestamp internally is 8 bytes binary field. In a table there can be only one field of that type, but I need two for synchro purpose.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps) help you?

Comment: I am not so sure. There the author is using one rowversion column and two smalldatetime columns. I wanted to do something like this: http://alexduggleby.com/2007/12/16/sync-framework-tutorial-part-3-preparing-the-server-database/ (Fragment of the article: Track update time and track insert time)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but  :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(8), CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE()) AS TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Generally I need these two columns for synchro purpose. One column (timestamp type) is for incrementing modifications in the record, and the insert timestamp for a new record being inserted. Dividing operation on these two fields would give me the opportunity to check which records were insrted from the last sync and which updated. I just only think what should be inserted there manually (for new records)...