# Update binary(8) field with optimized string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to update a field called `timestamp` of datatype `binary(8)` with an optimized 'timestamp' value.

I've tried the following:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); // this shows as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
$timestamp = strtotime($date); // this shows as 1412850218
```

When I try to insert `$timestamp` into the `binary(8)` field I get told that datatype `varchar` is not compatible with datatype `binary`. [This is to be expected](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-data-types.htm).

How do I optimize the string `1412850218` to be compatible with datatype `binary(8)` using PHP?

Or (even better) how do I define a default constraint in SQL that will fill the field automatically when a row is inserted?

I've looked at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801169/how-to-generate-timestamp-value-for-binary8-field) but the OP's comments revealed that he/she wanted to be able to create *two* `binary(8)` fields in *one* table, which doesn't help this question.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express.

**EDIT**

```
// NEW TIMESTAMP VARIABLE
$time = time();
$Timestamp = pack('H*', $time); // converted to binary as suggested

// PDO AND SQL CODE
$INSERT_STATEMENT = $DBH->prepare(" // $DBH is defined and connects fine
    INSERT INTO table (
        Timestamp
    ) VALUES (
        :Timestamp
    )
");
$INSERT_STATEMENT->bindParam(':Timestamp', $Timestamp);

if($INSERT_STATEMENT->execute()){
    // redirect
}else{
    print_r($INSERT_STATEMENT->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: First off, your method of generating a timestamp is quite silly since you just need `$timestamp = time();`, if you are not converting from an already existing date. The second thing that I find odd is using binary to save a timestamp - there are proper data formats for that in any relational db. However, to answer your question = you need to pack the integer you got from PHP into a binary string (at least I assume that's the case). To do that, you'd use this: `$time = time(); $binary = pack('H*', $time);`.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for that, I tried the above and it returned a PDO error: `Array ( [0] => IMSSP [1] => -7 [2] => An error occurred translating string for input param 18 to UCS-2: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. )`

Comment: @N.B. I did not create the table, I merely have to update it. I agree that it is odd to use a `binary` field to store a timestamp.

Comment: Can you post your PDO code as well please?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to tell your SQLServer that you're sending it binary object. `$INSERT_STATEMENT->bindValue(':Timestamp', $Timestamp, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);`. Could you try with that?

Comment: @N.B. Ok, I see what you're saying, I tried adding `$INSERT_STATEMENT->bindParam(':Timestamp', $Timestamp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);` but I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62748/discussion-between-prophet-and-n-b).