# execute constraint on update sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a constraint that return datetime for a column (date). 
On insert work it! Now I would like update column date with new value of getdate() when an update statement execute.  Any idea?

My constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD CONSTRAINT [constraintName]
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [column]
```

MY DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "on update don't change the value".  [edit] your question and show us your `insert` and `update` statements and the **exact** error message you get. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps

Comment: The only way you could do this is through a trigger. Have a look at those [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updTableDate
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE [Table] SET modified = GETDATE() WHERE [primary_key] IN (SELECT [primary_key] FROM INSERTED)
END
```

Or better:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updTableDate
ON [Table] 
AFTER UPDATE   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE [Table] t SET modified = GetDate() FROM INSERTED AS i WHERE t.id = i.id 
END
```