# Using Dapper to Insert into a Table with Default Values

Tags: dapper-extensions

I have a table that has a field that is not null and has a default value defined

```
[CreatedOn] not null default(getdate())
```

The the property I use in the model for dapper is a nullable DateTime

```
public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

If I try to insert, an exception is thrown for trying to insert an null value in a not null field.

```
cm.Insert<MyObject>(obj); //Throws because CreatedOn == null
```

What I'm looking for is the default to be set by the database, and to still be able to see that value when I read objects. Because Dapper is passing the value as null, the database throws the error. If I ignore the property then I lose the ability to read it. I'm hoping for a one way ignore, or a flag to let dapper know there will be a default. How does one make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Question above, I handle dapper defaults very simply by adding them in the constructor.  In your case this would like like so:

```
  [Table("my_objects")]
  public class MyObject
  {
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
      CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
  }
```

However, if you are attempting to handle created_at and updated_at through dapper rather than in the database, i would advise following a route like i have outlined here - [Dapper control dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218412/dapper-control-dates/40266916#40266916)

Lastly, if you want the database to handle this field, you can use the following example:

```
  [Table("my_objects")]
  public class MyObject
  {
    [Dapper.IgnoreUpdate, Dapper.IgnoreInsert]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is the default to be set by the database, and to still be able to see that value when I read objects. Because Dapper is passing the value as null, the database throws the error. If I ignore the property then I lose the ability to read it. I'm hoping for a one way ignore, or a flag to let dapper know there will be a default.

Comment: Ahhh, you can use the following attributes over CreatedOn -   [Dapper.IgnoreUpdate, Dapper.IgnoreInsert].  I edited the above example to show how this attribute fits in.   This will prevent DapperSimpleCrud from using them on inserts or updates.

Comment: What namespace are those attributes in? Dapper.Contrib has an attribute called Write, which takes a true of false, but dose not prevent the write.

Comment: these are present in DapperSimpleCrud - https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD

Comment: I tried to confirm this but I think it was prevented by multiple references to the base dapper extensions throughout the solution. I'll create a reference project with just dapper.simplecrud and try again.