# Changeing a TIMESTAMP column from NULL to NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS-SQL database with a lot of tables that have a TIMESTAMP column. Most of these columns are not nullable, but a few of them are, so I wanted to change the ones that are nullable to being not nullable.

But the following SQL statement that I googled and that should change a column from being nullable to being not nullable doesn't work

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT o.name FROM sysobjects o WHERE o.xtype='U' AND o.name='TableName')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN [Timestamp] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
END
```

The SQL server tells me, that the Timestamp column can't be changed to the timestamp data type (what I'm not doing).

Is something wrong with my statement or can't a TIMESTAMP column be set to being not nullable once it has been created nullable?
Is there a way to change the nullability of a column without giving it's datatype?
Or do I really have to delete the column completely and recreate it again?

I know that it's frowned upon to give columns names that equal certain keywords, but it is like it is and I can't change it.

SQL-Server 2008 R2 and later are used.

Comment: What is the current data type of the "Timestamp" column? SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Timestamp'. Verify it's actually a "timestamp" typed column, and not a datetime or datetime2.

Comment: Posting the error is really useful, but I suspect the error you are getting is: `Cannot alter column 'ts' to be data type timestamp.`

Comment: timestamp ( / AKA rowversion ! ) may not be what you think it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps/17116641#17116641

Comment: The columns named "Timestamp" are of type "timestamp". I know that the timestamp field will never be null. I look for a way to make a timestamp column not nullable, if it was created nullable.

Comment: The error message was in german and it translates to the one I mentioned above. It should be close to "The '%1' column can not be changed to the '%2' data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question (or what I think your question is), `timestamp` is a synonym for `rowversion`. You cannot change a column to be a `timestamp`/`rowversion` column. Also, a column declared as a `timestamp`/`rowversion` will never have a `NULL` value. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87609151bb7d38309ceb253192708d86) To quote the documentation ([rowversion (Transact-SQL) - Remarks (snippet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)):

> Every time that a row with a rowversion column is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is inserted in the rowversion column.

If you need to add a `rowversion` after the creation of the table they will all be given a value for `rowversion` then as well. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00972d40cab58369e3923b212379549e)

It's worth noting, as well, that `rowversion` is deprecated (to quote above documentation):

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

I suspect what you are really after here is a `date(time)` modified column, which is a completely different thing. `timestamp` despite is name, have nothing to do with time:

> The `rowversion` data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a `datetime2` data type.

So, as the documentation say, use `datetime2` (or another date(time) datatype).

Comment: In re: deprecation, I think they're specifically deprecating the `timestamp` synonym for `rowversion`, not the concept itself.

Comment: No, I really mean a timestamp column. We use this column to detect, if the data has changed between two reads of the data.

Comment: I read, that "timestamp" is supposed to be depracated, but I wonder why the SQL Server Management Studio is still using "timestamp" over "rowversion". So, I can create a table with a timestamp column and another table with a rowversion column. Both columns are shown as being of datatype "timestamp", and using the scripting ability of the SSMS for both tables, SSMS is using "timestamp" rather than "rowversion" in the created scripts.

Comment: I don't want to change a column to be of type "timestamp" (or "rowversion" for that matter). I'd like to change a column that is already of type "timestamp" to be not nullable.

Comment: @Nostromo but a `timestamp` column can **never** be `NULL`, as I said (and showed).

Comment: @BenThul you might be right there, not sure. I never make use of `rowversion`/`timestamp`; I prefer a actual date & time versioning column.

Comment: @Nostromo  if you really want a non-`NULL` column you'll have to `DROP` the existing column and add a new `timestamp` (`rowversion`) column. That, however, is unlikely to be what you are after.

Comment: To each their own. They serve different purposes though. `rowversion` is more about a cheap-ish way to determine "has this row changed in any way?" and, as an implementation detail "has this row been changed before/after this other row?" (by virtue of the monotonicity of the value in time). What you prefer (which is more in the family of `datetime`) might have collisions (even if you resolve down to the nanosecond!) but does provide you a way to collocate a particular row to wallclock time. Assuming that whomever wrote the row also faithfully kept that column up to date...

Comment: @Larnu: That's exactly what I'm after. I was hoping for a way to make a nullable timestamp column not nullable without dropping it, but one can't have it all...
Thank you.