# Issue with Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am working with an insert trigger and work fine. I am creating an insert trigger and take a backup in `tblHist` table.

I have two tables:

- `tblUser` - creating this table for insert,update and delete purpose
- `tblHist` - creating this table for store a record for history purpose

**tblUser** table design:

[image: tblUser Detail]

**tblHist** table design:

[image: tblHist Detail]

Then I create an insert and update trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgr_tblUser_AFTERINSERT] 
ON [dbo].[tblUser]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
   --,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userid int, @username varchar(50), 
            @useraddress varchar(50), @countryname varchar(5),
            @statename varchar(50), @cityname varchar(50);
     
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @userid = u.userid, @username = u.username, 
            @useraddress = u.useraddress,
            @countryname = u.countryname,
            @statename = u.statename, @cityname = u.cityname 
        FROM tblUser u;
    
        INSERT INTO tblHist (userid, username, useraddress, countryname,  statename, cityname)
        VALUES (@userid, @username, @useraddress, @countryname, @statename, @cityname);  
  
        PRINT 'AFTER INSERT update trigger fired.'  
    END
END
```

When I insert a record into the `tblUser` table, then it inserts a record into the `tblHist` table - this is working fine.

See below

[image]

Then I update a record then insert a history in `tblHist` table working fine.

[image]

but issue is when I add a code for delete a record functionality in `trgr_tblUser_AFTERINSERT` then delete functionality not work

And when I create a delete trigger separately then work fine

See below

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgr_tblUser_AFTERDELETE]
ON [dbo].[tblUser] 
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @userid int, @username varchar(50), 
            @useraddress varchar(50), @countryname varchar(5),
            @statename varchar(50), @cityname varchar(50);
    
    SELECT
        @userid = u.userid, @username = u.username, 
        @useraddress = u.useraddress, @countryname = u.countryname,
        @statename = u.statename, @cityname = u.cityname 
    FROM deleted u;
    
    INSERT INTO tblHist (userid, username, useraddress, countryname, statename, cityname)
    VALUES (@userid, @username, @useraddress, @countryname, @statename, @cityname);  
    
    PRINT 'AFTER DELETE trigger fired.'     
END
```

[image]

I want to add insert, update, delete trigger functionality In one trigger but not work.

What I am trying:

```
exist select 1  --- but not work
```

which place I am doing wrong need help

Comment: Simplest solution: create **three** separate triggers - once for each operation. Then you don't need to do lots of checking to figure out what operation you're dealing with. And also: in SQL Server, a trigger will be called **once per statement** (not once per row) - so when you select from `Inserted` or `Deleted` pseudo tables - **always** assume there are **multiple rows** in those tables! Your current `SELECT` will just pull **one** row from `Deleted` - what about all the other rows?? You need to use a **set-based** approach - not a "row-by-agonizing-row" one...

Comment: as marc_s mentions, triggers are SET BASED.  If you have table with rows and do a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE (with no where filter), the trigger fires ONCE for all 100 rows.  defining single @scalarVariables in a trigger will not work as you need.

Comment: this is a decent learning example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps/17116641#17116641

Comment: Any particular reason why there can be a user with all columns null?

Comment: As you have now discovered (or at least been told), your code does not "work fine". You need to improve the way you test and validate your code; your tests are all way to simplistic to discover these significant problems. And another note - a statement that affects zero (none) rows will also cause any associated triggers to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **highly** doubt that your first trigger will work properly .... you're just selecting an arbitrary rows from your `tblUser`  table - not even one that's necessarily just been inserted or updated ....

I would **strongly** recommend these changes:

- creating a **separate** trigger for **each operation** - that makes the trigger simpler, since you don't need to first figure out what you're dealing with....
- add a `ModifiedOn DATETIME2(3)` column to your `tblHist` to record the date & time stamp when the change occurred
- also possibly add an `Operation` column to your `tblHist` - so that you can understand what operation (insert, update, delete) caused this entry in the history table
- properly handle the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables in your trigger code taking into account they can (and **will!**) contain multiple rows - handle them in a proper, set-based fashion
- drop the `PRINT` - makes no sense inside a trigger....

Code would be something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trgr_tblUser_AfterInsert
ON dbo.tblUser
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- do an "INSERT INTO" ...
    INSERT INTO tblHist (ModifiedOn, userid, username, useraddress, countryname,  statename, cityname)
        -- based on the "Inserted" pseudo table, and use proper set-based approach
        SELECT 
            SYSDATETIME(),
            i.userid, i.username, i.useraddress, i.countryname, i.statename, i.cityname 
        FROM   
            Inserted i;
    END
END
```

and

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trgr_tblUser_AfterDelete
ON dbo.tblUser
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblHist (ModifiedOn, userid, username, useraddress, countryname,  statename, cityname)
        SELECT 
            SYSDATETIME(),
            d.userid, d.username, d.useraddress, d.countryname, d.statename, d.cityname 
        FROM   
            Deleted d;
    END
END
```

Comment: thanks for explaination but what about update trigger? means which place I add update keyword for update the trigger? can you please describle which place I can add update trigger for update the record

Comment: `CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trgr_tblUser_AfterUpdate ON dbo.tblUser AFTER UPDATE` - or what do you mean?? Sorry, not clear to me what you're really asking ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether it was an insert, update or delete, you have to examine the row count of the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudotables - for an insert, records are only present in `inserted`, for delete they are only present in `deleted`. An update has both so you can tell the old values (deleted) and the new (inserted)

Make your life easy; put twice as many columns in your hist (should be called UserHist, no?) table as your user table, and make them e.g. `old_username`, `new_username`.. an insert the result of a full outer join between the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, this way you can tell if it was an insert, update or delete and particularly for an insert, what changed to what

Alternatively, use something like

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT null FROM inserted) 
     IF EXISTS(SELECT null FROM deleted) 
       --it was an update
     ELSE
       --it was an insert
     END;
   ELSE
     --it was a delete
   END;
```

Or, make 3 separate triggers

---

Final point of note, you're doing these queries wrong - you're declaring a bunch of variables (that can only hold a single value)and selecting the values from `inserted`/`deleted` into them but those pseudotables can have more than one row, if the query affected multiple rows (such as `DELETE FROM user WHERE name = 'John'`)

You should be doing your operations in a bunch-of-rows way, not a "single row" way:

```
INSERT INTO tblHist
SELECT * FROM inserted
```

This *can* insert multiple rows into hist, and this is the way you should always think about doing things in SQLServer.. Even if you only ever insert one row and your `inserted` pseudotable has one row, you must get into the habit of treating it as "a collection of rows with one entry" so that any code you write won't fall apart when one day it becomes "a collection of rows with multiple entries"

---

Note in one of your attempts you did not select from `inserted`, you selected from the users table - this is wrong:

[image]

Of course, an AFTER delete trigger will insert nothing if you just deleted the only row from tblusers, but you shouldn't be using tblusers anyway