# The use of timestamp in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-timestamp

I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`. I am trying to create this database, but I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong with the timestamp; it has to default now.

This is the `Create Table` query:

```
create table users(
    id int identity primary key,
    username varchar(255) unique,
    created_at date, TIMESTAMP default)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `created_at date, TIMESTAMP default` This is not valid tsql - and we cannot know what your actual goal is. As a general suggestion, you should always include any error message your encountered. Unfortunately that message won't help readers here since no one knows your goal. TIMESTAMP is a deprecated datatype and shouldn't be used. But I suggest you leave database design and creation to others until AFTER you master tsql. Then learn the fundamentals of relational database design.

Comment: `timestamp`, in T-SQL, is a (as @SMor mentioned) is deprecated and is a synonym for `rowversion` (which is *not* deprecated); both are a `binary(8)` value and have **nothing** to do with dates and times. If you want a `rowversion` value then the correct syntax is `{Column Name} rowversion}`. If you are actually after some kind of date and time value, then you several [date and time data types](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types) to pick from. If you want a `DEFAULT` value, you need to *define* that value too. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps/17116641#17116641

Answer (score 0):

For a column `date` use `default getdate()`
for a column `datetime` use `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

> ```
> create table users(
>     id int identity primary key,
>     username varchar(255) unique,
>     created_date date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
>     created_date_time datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into users ( username) values ('new user');
> GO
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from users
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | created_date | created_date_time      
> -: | :------- | :----------- | :----------------------
>  1 | new user | 2022-05-31   | 2022-05-31 13:19:41.830
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f63e2721823c9ff3a3ff7d789043caf3)*