# Converting Postgresql Function to SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Our company is in planning to move a Postgres database to SQL Server. This includes all tables, functions and stored procedures etc.

Here is the Postgresql syntax:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION ex.on_update_integrity_reset()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN 
    new."integrity_error_id" := 0 ;
    new."requires_processing" := True ;
    new."datetime_amended" := now();
    return new ;
END;
$$;
```

I have tried the following conversion BUT no luck I am afraid. I am hoping that the solution is quite straight forward. Any assistance will be gratefully received.

My T-SQL syntax, which isn't working:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ex.on_update_integrity_reset()
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN atomic
    new."integrity_error_id" := 0 ;
    new."requires_processing" := True ;
    new."datetime_amended" := GETDATE();
    return new ;
END;
```

Comment: You've just dumped PostgreSQL into a SQL Server function's definition here and expected it to "just work". plgsql and T-SQL are *completely* different.

Comment: Triggers are written **completely** differently in SQL Server. You don't write functions that return tables. You write a trigger.

Comment: Here is an answer I did about a specific use of a trigger...... called "trgKeepUpdateDateInSync_ByeByeBye"  If you run the sample (which is working completely from the answer). you should get a glimpse of how a SET BASED trigger works.  if you internet search for Ms sql server triggers, make sure whatever you read is considering "SET BASED"...or your (RBAR row by agonizing row) trigger will let you down.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116334/sql-server-2008-row-insert-and-update-timestamps/17116641#17116641

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge amount of differences between Postgres' pgSQL and SQL Server's T-SQL, triggers not the least of them. You *must* learn the differences [**from the documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), rather than dumping in code and expecting it to just "work".

The key things to note about triggers in SQL Server:

- Triggers are directly defined on the table, rather than being separate functions which you can call.
- Triggers are run *per-statement* not *per-row*, and the pseudo-tables `inserted` and `deleted` may contain multiple or zero rows.
- `SET NOCOUNT ON` is ideal, due to problems with certain client drivers.
- Do not return resultsets from triggers, instead make any updates, inserts or deletes you wish, taking into account the pseudo-tables.

Here is an example for your use case:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.on_update_integrity_reset ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT -- what about updates???
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;  -- early bail-out

UPDATE t
SET
    integrity_error_id = 0,
    requires_processing = 1,  -- boolean type is not supported
    datetime_amended = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.YourTable t
JOIN inserted i ON i.SomePrimaryKey = t.SomePrimaryKey;
```

Be that as it may, you probably don't actually want a trigger. Instead, you probably need `DEFAULT` constraints. Although there are [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487144/14868997) for an auto-updating `datetime` column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR integrity_error_id;

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD DEFAULT 1 FOR requires_processing;

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR datetime_amended;
```