# How to create a trigger in SQL Server that insert values into two tables using an ID stored in the second one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have three tables:

- `RawValues` that contains Timestamp, Part, PartNumber,ValueKind, ... , Value
- `Measurements` that contains TimeStamp, ID, Value.
- `Hashtable` that contains ID, Part, ValueKind, ...

I have a stream of data that come into `RawValue` that I cannot modify. It contains all the columns except the ID.

I want to create a trigger on `RawValues` that insert the values into `Hashtable` (if they do not yet exist), select the id from `Hashtable` and then insert the row into `Measurements`.

This is what I've created:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TrigInsertToMeasurements]
ON [dbo].[MeasurementsTemp]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

       -- Dichiaro le variaibili --
       DECLARE 
             @TimeStamp datetime, 
             @MachineType char(10), 
             @MachineModel char(10), 
             @MachineNumber int, 
             @Part char(10),
             @PartNumber int,
             @ValueKind char(10),
             @Value float,
             @ID     int

       -- Assegno i valori --
       SELECT 
             @TimeStamp = TimeStamp,
             @MachineType = MachineType,
             @MachineModel = MachineModel,
             @MachineNumber = MachineNumber, 
             @Part = Part,
             @PartNumber = PartNumber,
             @ValueKind = ValueKind,
             @Value = Value
       FROM
             inserted


        SELECT @ID=ID FROM [dbo].[Hashtable]
        WHERE 
             @MachineType = [MachineType] AND
             @MachineModel = [MachineModel] AND
             @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
             @Part = Part AND
             @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
             @ValueKind = ValueKind


        IF count(@ID) = count(@TimeStamp)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] ) VALUES (@TimeStamp, @ID, @Value)
        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[Hashtable] WHERE
             @MachineType = [MachineType] AND
             @MachineModel = [MachineModel] AND
             @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
             @Part = Part AND
             @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
             @ValueKind = ValueKind)
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Hashtable] (MachineType, MachineModel, MachineNumber, Part, PartNumber, ValueKind)
            VALUES (@MachineType, @MachineModel, @MachineNumber, @Part, @PartNumber, @ValueKind)
            END
            END         

            SELECT @ID=ID FROM [dbo].[Hashtable]
            WHERE 
             @MachineType = MachineType AND
             @MachineModel = MachineModel AND 
             @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
             @Part = Part AND
             @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
             @ValueKind = ValueKind

             INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] ) VALUES (@TimeStamp, @ID, @Value)
        END
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MeasurementsTemp] ENABLE TRIGGER [TrigInsertToMeasurements]
GO
```

The trigger works correctly but sometime in the stream comes rows in groups, then in this case not all the rows are considered.
What can I do? Maybe use a for loop and then access to the arrays? How to do it?

Comment: your concept of trigger is wrong. Trigger occurs not for each record. the INSERTED may contains more than 1 row. You need to handle that in your trigger

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. You cannot just simply do a `SELECT .... FROM Inserted` - you'll get only *one arbitrary* row and *ignore all others* - typically not what you want to do. You need to completely **rewrite your trigger** in a set-based fashion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple records in a MS SQL trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662010/handling-multiple-records-in-a-ms-sql-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

i try to re-code your trigger, replacing it accordinlgy best to my understanding of the logic

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TrigInsertToMeasurements]
ON [dbo].[MeasurementsTemp]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

       -- Dichiaro le variaibili --
       DECLARE 
             @TimeStamp datetime, 
             @MachineType char(10), 
             @MachineModel char(10), 
             @MachineNumber int, 
             @Part char(10),
             @PartNumber int,
             @ValueKind char(10),
             @Value float,
             @ID     int

       -- Assegno i valori --
       --SELECT 
       --      @TimeStamp = TimeStamp,
       --      @MachineType = MachineType,
       --      @MachineModel = MachineModel,
       --      @MachineNumber = MachineNumber, 
       --      @Part = Part,
       --      @PartNumber = PartNumber,
       --      @ValueKind = ValueKind,
       --      @Value = Value
       --FROM
       --      inserted


        --SELECT @ID=ID FROM [dbo].[Hashtable]
        --WHERE 
        --     @MachineType = [MachineType] AND
        --     @MachineModel = [MachineModel] AND
        --     @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
        --     @Part = Part AND
        --     @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
        --     @ValueKind = ValueKind


        IF count(@ID) = count(@TimeStamp)
        BEGIN
            --INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] ) VALUES (@TimeStamp, @ID, @Value)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] ) 
        SELECT  i.TimeStamp, h.ID, i.Value
        FROM    inserted i
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Hashtable] h  ON  i.[MachineType]     = h.[MachineType]
                            AND i.[MachineModel]    = h.[MachineModel]
                            AND i.MachineNumber     = h.MachineNumber
                            AND i.Part          = h.Part
                            AND i.PartNumber        = h.PartNumber
                            AND i.ValueKind     = h.ValueKind
        WHERE   i.TimeStamp IS NOT NULL

        END
        ELSE 
    BEGIN

      --      BEGIN
            --IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[Hashtable] WHERE
            -- @MachineType = [MachineType] AND
            -- @MachineModel = [MachineModel] AND
            -- @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
            -- @Part = Part AND
            -- @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
            -- @ValueKind = ValueKind)
               -- BEGIN
               -- INSERT INTO [dbo].[Hashtable] (MachineType, MachineModel, MachineNumber, Part, PartNumber, ValueKind)
               -- VALUES (@MachineType, @MachineModel, @MachineNumber, @Part, @PartNumber, @ValueKind)
               -- END
      --      END    
           INSERT INTO [dbo].[Hashtable] (MachineType, MachineModel, MachineNumber, Part, PartNumber, ValueKind)
       SELECT   i.MachineType, i.MachineModel, i.MachineNumber, i.Part, i.PartNumber, i.ValueKind
       FROM     inserted i
       WHERE    NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    [dbo].[Hashtable] x
                WHERE   x.MachineType   = i.MachineType
                AND x.MachineModel  = i.MachineModel
                AND x.MachineNumber = i.MachineNumber
                AND x.Part      = i.Part
                AND x.PartNumber    = i.PartNumber
                AND x.ValueKind = i.ValueKind
            )

            --SELECT @ID=ID FROM [dbo].[Hashtable]
            --WHERE 
            -- @MachineType = MachineType AND
            -- @MachineModel = MachineModel AND 
            -- @MachineNumber = MachineNumber AND
            -- @Part = Part AND
            -- @PartNumber = PartNumber AND
            -- @ValueKind = ValueKind

            -- INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] ) VALUES (@TimeStamp, @ID, @Value)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurements] ([TimeStamp], [ID], [Value] )
        SELECT  i.[TimeStamp], h.ID, i.Value
        FROM    inserted i
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Hashtable] h  ON  i.MachineType   = h.MachineType
                            AND i.MachineModel  = h.MachineModel
                            AND i.MachineNumber = h.MachineNumber
                            AND i.Part      = h.Part
                            AND i.PartNumber    = h.PartNumber
                            AND i.ValueKind = h.ValueKind
        END
END
```