# How to store multiple records in a single column in trigger table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a new trigger with table name as advance_audit, and I have a employee table, whenever user updates more than one column in employee form, I want to store those values in advance_audit table in old_value column. If user edits two records then two records should save in old_Value column,

At present only  firstname  is saving, i want to store other fields also like lastname. How to do it

Below is my code.

```
Insert into advance_audit
set action='update'
old_value =old.firstname
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question sound like: [Handling multiple records in a MS SQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662010/handling-multiple-records-in-a-ms-sql-trigger). Can you add more info about your table structure, and the trigger you currently have defined?

Comment: *trigger table* What do you mean? *If user edits two records then two records should save in old_Value column* trigger firing works with single row, hence only two rows with one value in each row is possible. *Below is my code.* This is single query, not trigger code.

Comment: @Luuk MySQL, not MS SQL.